# python tools for visual studio and primitive highlighting?

Tags: python, visual-studio-2010

How can I get things like `None`, `False`, `True` get highlighted? I think they do deserve highlights..

Comment: To be clear, you're talking about http://pytools.codeplex.com/ ?

Comment: ya, and that tool does not highlight very important words like `None`, `True`, `False`

Answer (score 1):

In Python 2.x, True, False, and None are not keywords, merely global variables.

Apparently, if you use Python 3.x, True and False should be highlighted.

Source:
https://pytools.codeplex.com/workitem/803

Answer (score 0):

I am aware of two extensions for Visual Studio that support Python. I did not use any of them (I prefer Eclipse with PyDev or text editor), but you can try:

http://pytools.codeplex.com/

http://www.ironpython.net/tools/

Answer (score 0):

Are you running Iron Python?
If so are you also running Python Tools for Visual Studio: http://pytools.codeplex.com/

Comment: Wow, a down vote for trying to help out - Perhaps the question should be closed for being non-productive and certainly not descriptive enough.